# Deep comparison for HashSet in Java

Tags: java, set, equals, hashset

So I'm doing a search method and my `HashSet<GameBoard> explored` has all the explored states. I need to add more states to "explored" so I don't check the same state over and over again. I need to compare states with a copy of itself and if the VALUE of them are the same, I don't check it again. 
I know I have to override the `.equals()`method in Obj class for it to do a deep search and I did just that. Below is my equals method.

```
public boolean equals  (GameBoard a){
    for(int j = 0;j < a.len;j++){
        if(a.boardArr[j] != this.boardArr[j]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I add GameBoard to explored using `explored.add(state);`. But this doesn't seem to do anything. I even commented out the equals method completely and the result is the same. It keeps adding the same state to the explored state and hence I have an infinite loop. Really need some help here does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The param type needs to be Object. SImply put the @Override annotation on methods that you think override something, and the compiler will tell you when you got something wrong!

Comment: @rabbitguy The method has the wrong signature. It is not relevant what it is doing until that is fixed.

Comment: Sorry I used <Obj> just as a general object, which is gameboard, I'll edit it

Comment: I mean: the parameter for the equals method is wrong!